On the decomposition of a Jordan base
I am trying to prove the following:
$\beta$ is a Jordan basis iff $\beta=\beta_1\cup\dots\cup\beta_r$, where each $\beta_i$ are distinct cycles of generalized eigenvectors of T
I have some ideas but I don't know if I'm on the right track:
I can write $V=K_{\lambda_1}\oplus\dots\oplus K_{\lambda_r}$, with each $\lambda_i$ an eigenvector of $T$ and $K_{\lambda_i}$ the generalized eigenspace associated to $\lambda_i$
For each $v\in K_{\lambda}$ I can construct the Jordan chain $C=\{(T-\lambda 1)^{m-1}(v),\dots, (T-\lambda 1)(v), v\}$ , which is a cycle  of generalized eigenvectors of T. I know that if $C_1, C_j,\dots C_r$ are the cycles of generalized eigenvectors associated to $\lambda$ such that their initial vectors are linearly independent, then the cycles $C_i$ are distinct pair by pair and the union is linearly independent.
From this point I don't know exactly how to continue, and it seems to me that my analysis is in disarray, any ideas to conclude ($\implies$)?

May I ask, why are you proving this? Is it an exercise set by a text book or something like that? Or a self-imposed challenge? This seems like an odd exercise, because it's not difficult to explain, but it is tedious to write up formally. Essentially, it follows from the block structure of a Jordan matrix; once you have certain columns forming a Jordan block, those corresponding vectors in the basis have to be an eigenvector chain, and vice-versa. You just use the definition of a matrix for the operator, under a given basis.

@TheoBendit It is an exercise proposed in my class, and yes, maybe it is because it is difficult to write, but I think I have the idea.
